# Problem with curve fit using integral

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting, nonlinear

I need fitting a Langevin function on a experimental data, but one parameter must be firstly optimized by using a Lognormal distribution. 
The complete expression could be written as:

[image]

The integrate variable is `t` and the `d` parameter (together `w`) must be optimized before uses in the fitting equation.
Thus, lognormal distribution parameters are: `A`, `w`, `d`
and the fitting parameters are: `y0`, `Ms`, `b`, `c`

Please, note that the variable is `x`, but the integral is related to `t`. Thus, `d` parameter must be previously optimized to be used in each interaction step. 
Although I believe that *Mathematica* could solve this, I have no idea how to resolve the problem!
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Please post the corresponding Mathematica code for the expression, not an image

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!